# Flutter can't see the image

Tags: flutter

Flutter doesn't see the image. In `pubspec.yaml` I specified everything correctly but there is still no image. I tried writing the exact location in `pubspec.yaml` but there is no difference and I do not know the reason why it is highlighted with a yellow wavy line.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 3):

Do not make folder under `lib` folder. Your structure for assets folder as per below.

[image]

And `pubspecs.yaml`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a low bow, I'm such a fool damn thank you

Comment: Hahahah, Its okay, Approve my answer if it works,

Comment: There is a small problem why flutter says that the location is specified incorrectly but the images are shown on the device it's about that yellow underscore

Comment: restart your project and then check again.

Comment: Welcome and approve my answer, Keep Growing ^^

Answer (score 0):

The folder `assets` should not be inside the `lib`

[image]